# What does text inside a red rectangle in VS Code mean?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

What does text inside a red rectangle in VS Code mean?

If I just start typing outside of any file and outside anything (e.g. the `Ctrl+P` input, or the search input), then I am getting what I typed being added inside a red rectangle. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

The rectangle appeared in the right upper corner of my opened VS Code when I typed `Foo.js`. By rectangle I mean the filled one, the red border was added by me manually to highlight the filled rectangle.

I am very curious what is a purpose of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you get in red rectangle is the search that VScode performs on the version control changes for filename. You can type more to search specific files in you changes list.

You can click on that box to enable or disable filter based on what you typed

Answer (score 0):

This is the document tree filtering feature that appears to have been released in version 1.31, see the [Workbench section of the release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_workbench) more details.

The current ["Getting Started" docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_filtering-the-document-tree) states:

> You can type to filter the currently visible files in the File
>   Explorer. With the focus on the File Explorer start to type part of
>   the file name you want to match. You will see a filter box in the
>   top-right of the File Explorer showing what you have typed so far and
>   matching file names will be highlighted. When you press the cursor
>   keys to move up and down the file list, it will jump between matching
>   files or folders.
>
> Hovering over the filter box and selecting Enable Filter on Type will
>   show only matching files/folders. Use the 'X' Clear button to clear
>   the filter.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. :)